# Application crashes before requestLocationPermissions

Tags: android, geolocation, titanium

I am making application using ti.map on Titanium.

From Android6 
permission system is changing .
I have to give the permission not when installing but in the app running.

I made these code, but it works like this.

- At first launch.

If you try to show map,it crashes. However alert (Allow to access this device's location?) remains.

- Second launch
  If you touched yes at first launch. It works and correctly shows the map.

I think problem is ,crashes happen when trying to open the map before the return of the result of requestLocationPermissions dialog.

But, requestLocationPermissions dialog is triggered only when user try to open map by `Ti.Geolocation.requestLocationPermissions`.
So it is impossible to ask user the permission before opening map in advance.

So in summary

I would like to fire requestLocationPermissions callback in advance.

So this is my code.

```
if (Ti.Platform.osname === 'android'){
    var hasLocationPermissions = Ti.Geolocation.hasLocationPermissions(Ti.Geolocation.AUTHORIZATION_ALWAYS);
    Ti.API.info('Ti.Geolocation.hasLocationPermissions : ' +  hasLocationPermissions);
    if (hasLocationPermissions) {
        Ti.API.info('You already have permission.');
    }
    else {
        Ti.Geolocation.requestLocationPermissions(Ti.Geolocation.AUTHORIZATION_ALWAYS, function(e) {
            Ti.API.info('Ti.Geolocation.requestLocationPermissions' +  e);
            if (e.success) {
                // Instead, probably call the same method you call if hasLocationPermissions() is true
                alert('You granted permission.');

            } else if (OS_ANDROID) {
                alert('You denied permission for now, forever or the dialog did not show at all because it you denied forever before.');

            } else {

        // We already check AUTHORIZATION_DENIED earlier so we can be sure it was denied now and not before
                Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
                    title: 'You denied permission.',

                    // We also end up here if the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription is missing from tiapp.xml in which case e.error will say so
                    message: e.error
                }).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And error messages are below.

```
[ERROR] TiApplication: (main) [13751,15075] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.SecurityException: my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION; Titanium 6.0.1,2016/12/19 16:51,undefined
[ERROR] TiApplication: java.lang.SecurityException: my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.az.c(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:50297)
```

Comment: Have entered the **Google API key** to register your app? This may be a reason for crash.

Comment: yes , i have entered the Google API key. and map works correctly after first crash.

Comment: This code seems to be fine to me, I tried the same code and my app worked properly. Could you please update the question with code that you have written for loading the Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on Android call the function without params

```
Ti.Geolocation.hasLocationPermissions();
```

[Documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation-method-hasLocationPermissions)

Comment: I have added this though,Ti.map is called before user push OK. My ideal way is permission prompt appears -> ti.map open. However, even I set `Ti.Geolocation.hasLocationPermissions();` it shows the popup when some ti.map action triggered.

Comment: Sorry you are right I missunderstanding the problem. At the beginning popup appears by Ti.Geolocation.hasLocationPermissions(); however Another window overlay the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

set targetsdk version 21 to build.gradle. your problem will be solved.